# WPF Trigger on Drawn Button

Tags: wpf, templates, triggers, styles, controltemplate

I have made a triangle `Button` via some of the Questions ask here, everything working fine but now I want to add `Triggers` but nothing happens. I have two `Buttons` wich should have the some things happen on `IsMouseOver` but the Triangles point in different directions (< & >). So I tought I create one `Style` with all the Triggers and then have two styles inherit from this style and draw the triangles. But like I said nothing is happening.

**UPDATE after first 2 Anwers:**

```
<Style x:Key="DateTrigger" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>                                   
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>                                 
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="Back" BasedOn="{StaticResource DateTrigger}" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Polygon Stroke="Black" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Polygon.Points>
                            <Point X="74.2" Y="0"/>
                            <Point X="0" Y="25"/>
                            <Point X="74.2" Y="50"/>
                        </Polygon.Points>
                        </Polygon>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your `Trigger` to affect the `Background` property, but you haven't defined that property's use in your `ControlTemplate`. So, the `Background` property value may well be changing, but you can't see it because you are not using it in your `ControlTemplate`. You can access the `Background` property from the `ControlTemplate` using the [`TemplateBinding Markup Extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Border Name="border"
        BorderThickness="1"
        Padding="4,2"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        CornerRadius="1"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

I'm not sure why you say that the `Style` is still not working... it works just fine. Just apply your `Style` (including the `{TemplateBinding Background}`) to a `Button` and mouse over it:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource DateTrigger}" Content="Click me" />
```

I've just noticed that you've changed/removed your original code example... please don't do that because it means that answers, comments (and sometimes questions) no longer make sense. So anyway, your *original* code worked just fine (with the `{TemplateBinding Background}` added), so I'd replace it if I were you. Here's your original working code example that I edited:

```
<Style x:Key="DateTrigger" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="4,2"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        CornerRadius="1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="Back" BasedOn="{StaticResource DateTrigger}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Polygon Stroke="Black" Fill="White">
                    <Polygon.Points>
                        <Point X="74.2" Y="0"/>
                        <Point X="0" Y="25"/>
                        <Point X="74.2" Y="50"/>
                    </Polygon.Points>
                </Polygon>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

Well you just can't use that `Back Style`, because the `ControlTemplate` in it will replace the `ControlTemplate` in the `DateTrigger Style`, along with the `Triggers` section. To fix this, you can just add more `Triggers` into your `Back Style ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="Back" BasedOn="{StaticResource DateTrigger}" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Polygon Stroke="Black" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Polygon.Points>
                        <Point X="74.2" Y="0"/>
                        <Point X="0" Y="25"/>
                        <Point X="74.2" Y="50"/>
                    </Polygon.Points>
                </Polygon>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

...

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource Back}" Content="Click me" />
```

Comment: Alright sorry about that.
But if use the `DateTrigger` nothing is drawn because that Part is in the `Back` `Style`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that and have more styles inherit from the DateTrigger. But it seems that is not possible. But still thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your `Trigger` sets `Button.Background` and not `Border.Background` so you need to either set `TargetName` to name of the `Border`

```
<Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
```

or use `TemplateBinding` and bind `Button.Background` to `Border.Background`

```
<Border Name="border" ... Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

Second problem is that it seems to me that you think that `ControlTemplate` is somehow merged. This is not the case. When you set `Template` in `Back` style you overwrite value inherited from `DateTrigger` style effectively loosing all your triggers. One solution would be to set `Content` in `Back` style instead of `Template`

```
<Style x:Key="Back" BasedOn="{StaticResource DateTrigger}" TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Content">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Polygon Stroke="Black" Fill="White">
            <Polygon.Points>
               <Point X="74.2" Y="0"/>
               <Point X="0" Y="25"/>
               <Point X="74.2" Y="50"/>
            </Polygon.Points>
         </Polygon>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```